# How would I view a list of file paths in a Finder window from command line output?

Tags: terminal, finder, filesystem, search

Is there any way to take a list of file paths from `find` (or alike) and view them in a Finder window?

For example, say I'd like to see a **single** Finder window containing "all of the `.mp3` files in the current path and its subdirectories excluding the directory `archive/`".

I'd like to take this output:

```
$ find "$(pwd -P)" -iname "*.mp3 -not -path "./archive/*""
/Users/me/1.mp3
/Users/me/2.mp3
/Users/me/subdir/3.mp3
```

And view those files in a Finder window as if I was doing a regular Finder search.

I realize I can do an advanced search within Finder but for my purposes, it's too limited.

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 2):

How about temporarily assigning them all a unique label (maybe using something like [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag/)), and then making a Finder smart folder for that label?

Here's what I did:

1. Install `tag` with `brew install tag`.
2. In Finder, File > New Smart Folder.
3. Click "This Mac".
4. Click +, and add "Tags" "Is" `temp0`. (This will get replaced later with a new temporary tag.)
5. Click Save, and save it as something like `/Users/youruser/Library/Saved Searches/Custom Tag.savedSearch`.
6. Create a script like this (with `SMART_FOLDER` set to the path above, without the extension):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
SMART_FOLDER="/Users/youruser/Library/Saved Searches/Custom Tag" # without extension

# pass all arguments to find, and store in array
IFS=$'\n'
RESULTS=($(find "$@"))
unset IFS

# assign a temporary label
LABEL=temp$(date +%s)
tag -a "$LABEL" "${RESULTS[@]}"

# create a temporary savedSearch with the new label.
# if we just update it, Finder doesn't seem to notice.
sed "s/temp0/$LABEL/g" "$SMART_FOLDER.savedSearch" > "$SMART_FOLDER-$LABEL.savedSearch"
open "$SMART_FOLDER-$LABEL.savedSearch"

echo "Showing results for $LABEL. Press return to remove label."
read
tag -r "$LABEL" "${RESULTS[@]}"
rm "$SMART_FOLDER-$LABEL.savedSearch"
```

7. Save it as something like `ffind`, somewhere in your default $PATH.
8. Make it executable with `chmod u+x ffind`.
9. Now you can use it just like `find`, e.g. `ffind . -name '*.html'`. It will pass its arguments to `find`, assign a temporary label to the results, create a temporary smart folder that finds that label, and open it. Then it will wait for you to press return.
10. When you press return, it will clear the label from the files, and delete the temporary smart folder.

Answer (score 1):

A short AppleScript would work:

```
tell application "Finder" to reveal {"/Users/me/1.mp3" as POSIX file, "/Users/me/2.mp3" as POSIX file, "/Users/me/3.mp3" as POSIX file}
```

and you can run that directly from terminal with `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to reveal {"/Users/me/1.mp3" as POSIX file, "/Users/me/2.mp3" as POSIX file, "/Users/me/3.mp3" as POSIX file}'
```

I'm not proficient enough with shell to convert the `find` output to the above command (I'd rather use a text editor for this), but it should be doable.

Comment: Thanks, @Glorfindel. This is a start however if I have a file at `~/Desktop/1.mp3` and a file at `~/Desktop/subdir/2.mp3` the Finder will reveal them in separate tabs. In hindsight, I wasn't clear enough: I'd like all of the files to open in the same Finder window. Maybe this isn't doable.

Comment: Updated my post for clarification.

Comment: Ah, you mean it should take `~/Desktop` as the root folder and 'expand' the `subdir` folder (and select both files). I'm not sure if *that* is possible - I hope somebody else has a better solution then.